# XSLT: sum with condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to convert below XML through XSLT by groping based on **Name** tag and get the total sum of **Amount** tag with the condition **(Status = 'Draft')** . Please advise

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.test/bsvc">
    <wd:Entry>
        <wd:Name>ABC</wd:Name>
        <wd:ID>123</wd:ID>
        <wd:Amount>10</wd:Amount>
        <wd:Status>Pending</wd:Status>
    </wd:Entry>
    <wd:Entry>
        <wd:Name>ABC</wd:Name>
        <wd:ID>123</wd:ID>
        <wd:Amount>20</wd:Amount>
        <wd:Status>Draft</wd:Status>
    </wd:Entry>
    <wd:Entry>
        <wd:Name>ABC</wd:Name>
        <wd:ID>123</wd:ID>
        <wd:Amount>30</wd:Amount>
        <wd:Status>Draft</wd:Status>
    </wd:Entry>
</wd:Data>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.test/bsvc" exclude-result-prefixes="wd">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        
        
        <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Data/wd:Entry" group-by="wd:Name">
            
            
            <Details>
                <ID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:ID"/>
                </ID>
                <Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Name"/>
                </Name>
                <Total_Unverified_Amount>
                    <xsl:value-of select='format-number(sum(current-group()/wd:Amount),"##.00")'/>
                </Total_Unverified_Amount>
                <Charges_Draft>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/wd:Amount[current-group()/wd:Status = 'Draft'])"/>
                </Charges_Draft>
            </Details>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output generated:**

```
<Details>
   <ID>123</ID>
   <Name>ABC</Name>
   <Total_Unverified_Amount>60.00</Total_Unverified_Amount>
   <Charges_Draft>60</Charges_Draft>
</Details>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<Details>
   <ID>123</ID>
   <Name>ABC</Name>
   <Total_Unverified_Amount>60.00</Total_Unverified_Amount>
   <Charges_Draft>50</Charges_Draft>
</Details>
```

I would like to convert below XML through XSLT by groping based on **Name** tag and get the total sum of **Amount** tag with the condition **(Status = 'Draft')** . Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<Charges_Draft>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/wd:Amount[current-group()/wd:Status = 'Draft'])"/>
</Charges_Draft>
```

use:

```
<Charges_Draft>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()[wd:Status = 'Draft']/wd:Amount)"/>
</Charges_Draft>
```

---

To clarify: your predicate:

```
[current-group()/wd:Status = 'Draft']
```

returns true whenever there is at least one `wd:Entry` in the current group whose `wd:Status` is `"Draft"`. This result is then applied to all members of the current group being tested alike.